# Using DOMDocument to wrap all nodes between header tags in div

Tags: php, dom

I have a set of HTML files to process where related sections are not grouped in containers and can contain virtually any element.  New sections are currently only delineated by the next header tag:

```
<h1>Section 1</h1>
<p>Paragraph Text</p>
<p>Paragraph Text</p>

<h2>Section 2</h2>
<p>Paragraph Text</p>
<img src='an image' />
<p>Further Paragraph Text</p>

<h1>Section 3</h1>
<p>Paragraph Text</p>
<p>Paragraph Text</p>
```

How can I use the [DOM functions in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to wrap all content between these header tags in a `<div>`?  I.e. transforming the above HTML into:

```
<div>
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Paragraph Text</p>
    <p>Paragraph Text</p>
</div>

<div>
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <p>Paragraph Text</p>
    <img src='an image' />
    <p>Further Paragraph Text</p>
</div>

<div>
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Paragraph Text</p>
    <p>Paragraph Text</p>
</div>
```

So far I have tried various combinations of loops and XPATH selectors to try and gather all the elements between headers so that I can wrap them as above - but haven't been successful in doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial thoughts were based around manipulating the output buffer as I had failed to read the opening paragraph properly and the following function was used as a callback to `ob_start`.

You might notice the use of $tags towards the start of the function and followed by the rather complicted $query - the $tags is used later to aid populating found nodes and to ensure we stop when the next node found is in that $tags array - rather than write the pattern and maintain this array independently I figured it would be more flexible like this.

Essentially it works like this: Construct a query pattern from the supplied `$tags` array and use that to query the HTML DOM. If there are matching nodes, iterate through the collection and add the found node( a header ) to an array. Then iterate over the siblings of the found node and add these to the same new array. Before the loop moves to the next node in the collection save this array before repeating the process. Once all the discovered nodes have been processed it is time to create the container `DIV` elements ensuring that all children are once again populated.

```
<?php
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234379/using-domdocument-to-wrap-all-nodes-between-header-tags-in-div/59235431#59235431



    function wrapcallback( $buffer ){
        global $use_output_buffer;

        $delimiter='#';
        $tags=array('h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6');
        $query=implode('|', explode( $delimiter, sprintf( '//%s', implode( sprintf( '%s//', $delimiter ), $tags ) ) ) );
        $keepers=array();
        $parents=array();

        libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
        $dom=new DOMDocument;
        $dom->validateOnParse=false;
        $dom->recover=true;
        $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace=true;
        $dom->loadHTML( $buffer );
        $errors = libxml_get_errors();
        libxml_clear_errors();

        $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
        $col=$xp->query( $query );

        if( $col->length > 0 ){
            foreach( $col as $node ){

                $parents[]=$node->parentNode;
                $nodes=array( $node );

                while( $node = $node->nextSibling ){
                    if( in_array( $node->nodeName, $tags ) )break;
                    if( $node->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE  )$nodes[]=$node;
                }
                $keepers[]=$nodes;
            }
        }

        foreach( $keepers as $index => $obj ){
            $div=$dom->createElement('div');
            $parents[ $index ]->appendChild( $div );
            foreach( $obj as $child )$div->appendChild( $child );
        }

        $keepers = $parents = $xp = $div = null;
        echo $dom->saveHTML();
    };





    $html="
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
        <head>
            <title>It's a Christmas Wrapper!</title>
            <style>
                body{
                    background:url( https://storage.needpix.com/rsynced_images/christmas-wallpaper-1480711266Vyi.jpg );
                    background-repeat:repeat;
                    color:white;
                }

            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

                <h1>Section 1</h1>
                <p>Paragraph Text</p>
                <p>Paragraph Text</p>

                <h2>Section 2</h2>
                <p>Paragraph Text</p>
                <img src='/images/laracroft.png' />
                <p>Further Paragraph Text</p>

                <h1>Section 3</h1>
                <p>Paragraph Text</p>
                <p>Paragraph Text</p>

        </body>
    </html>";

    wrapcallback( $html );

?>
```

Comment: I have been struggling with this all day, you've taken a completely different approach to me and it works very well.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh - glad to hear it works for your needs.. good luck with the rest of the coding adventure

Comment: The above could be simplified if the parent node is always going to be the same parent node - would mean there would be no need to maintain the list of possible parentnodes but not much of a saving really